# TinyMCE - window.blur function firing on editor focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a `window.blur` function as follows

```
$(window).blur(function(){  
    _doing_something_wrong.resume();
    $('#_put_an_eye_on_users_activity_modal').modal({show : true, keyboard: false,backdrop: 'static'});
});
```

and `TinyMCE` `init` as follows

```
 tinymce.init({
    selector:'._editor_statement_question',
    setup: function (_editor) {
        _editor.on("focus", function () {
            $(this.contentAreaContainer.parentElement).find("div.mce-toolbar-grp").show();
        });
    }
 });
```

but whenever I am trying to type some content in `editor` ( `_editor.on('focus',function(){}` ) the `window.blur` function is firing, I mean the `modal` is showing up, 
How can I avoid this only for editor focus,

I tried `unbinding` the blur function, but need a simple and clean solution, some hints please

```
TinyMCE vesrion - 4.x
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, Its because of the `TinyMCE` `Iframe`, So I managed my `blur` function as follows

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    if($('iframe').is(':focus')) {
        //do nothing
    } 
    else {
        _doing_something_wrong.resume();
        $('#_put_an_eye_on_users_activity_modal').modal({show : true, keyboard: false,backdrop: 'static'});
    }
})
```